# tinyMCE change my obect tag to img

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am working on a CMS based on Zend Framwork and including TinyMCE 2.1.1.
Whene i  include a youtube URL then i click save the plugin change the  tag to an   tag !!

if i insert this :

```
<object height="100" width="100" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/zURQz7sdPYA" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/zUdPYA" />
</object>
```

I got this  :

```
    <img class="mceItemFlash" width="100" height="100" mce_src="/js/library/tiny_mce/plugins
/media/img/trans.gif" src="/js/library/tiny_mce/plugins/media/img/trans.gif" title=""src":"http://www.youtube.com/v/zUPYA"">
```

I have added this  :

```
 valid_elements : "object[classid|codebase|width|height|align|type|data],param[id|name|type|value|valuetype<DATA?OBJECT?REF]"
```

Or this, to the init.js file

```
 valid_elements : "*[*]",
```

Stll no changes ...

Can you help ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it !

```
function sendAjaxRequest(inst) {
Ext.Ajax.request( {
    url : '/index.php/page/session',
    // success: sucessMsg(),
    failure : failureMsg,
    params : {
        action : 'session',
        id : instBack,
        value : inst.getContent()//instead
        //value : inst.getBody().innerHTML
    }
});
```